# Deleting a cell from UITableView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2

When deleting a cell from the tableView, the animation runs fine, but the tableView data isn't reloaded. I tried running without `.beginUpdates()` and `.endUpdates()` and instead used `.reloadData()`, and the process worked but the animation didn't work.

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    switch editingStyle {
    case .Delete:
        // remove the deleted item from the model
        let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext
        context.deleteObject(coreData[indexPath.row] as NSManagedObject)
        coreData.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            print("Error deleting NSManagedObject")
        }


        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        tasks.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        names.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        ids.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        tableView.endUpdates()
        // remove the deleted item from the `UITableView`

    default:
        return

    }

}
```

By the way, the `tasks` array is the the main data for the tableView.

How can I reload the data as I delete a cell, WITH the smooth deletion animation?

Comment: What do you mean 'reload the data'?  Do you want to update the content of every other cell?  If so then you need to call reloadData after the end updates

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things to consider:

1. You must update the data model before you update the table view. Therefore the order of the code must be:

   ```
   tasks.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
   names.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
   ids.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
   tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
   ```
2. There is no need for the calls to `begin/endUpdates` since you only make a single call to update the table view.

Answer (score 2):

Move all the `removeAtIndex...` lines before the `beginUpdates` , u have to remove the object from the data first before u can delete row

Comment: No, as long as the data is removed before you call `endUpdates`

Comment: hmm...thats not wrong, maybe its his core data update?